# Dovecot fails to work with "IMAP plugin" after update

Tags: dovecot

I updated dovecot with custombuild to 2.2.22 version. After the update server crashed and had to be rebooted from the server. Update completed but dovecot service failed to start.

After reboot, I could not log in to any of the email accounts so I looked through dovecot logs and found this:

```
Apr 11 17:31:37 server dovecot[1435]: imap(mail@domain.com): Error: Couldn't load required plugin /usr/lib/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so: dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so: file too short
Apr 11 17:31:37 server dovecot[1435]: imap(mail@domain.com): Error: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
```

I cannot find any specific error in server log (if by that it means messages).

For now, I have removed imap_quota plugin from dovecot config and it is working (but no quota working ofcourse). Can anyone please help me fix this?

I'm running CentOS 6

Edit: Output of "ls -l /usr/lib/dovecot/":

```
[root@server ~]# ls -l /usr/lib/dovecot/
total 50916
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     4096 Apr 11 15:55 auth
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     4096 Apr 11 15:55 doveadm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      868 Apr 11 15:54 dovecot-config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1181086 Apr 11 15:55 lib01_acl_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      994 Apr 11 15:55 lib01_acl_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   552277 Apr 11 15:55 lib01_acl_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   136948 Apr 11 15:55 lib02_imap_acl_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1066 Apr 11 15:55 lib02_imap_acl_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    91748 Apr 11 15:55 lib02_imap_acl_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   126956 Apr 11 15:55 lib02_lazy_expunge_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1057 Apr 11 15:55 lib02_lazy_expunge_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    85652 Apr 11 15:55 lib02_lazy_expunge_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   160916 Apr 11 15:55 lib05_pop3_migration_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib05_pop3_migration_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib05_pop3_migration_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    93420 Apr 11 15:55 lib05_snarf_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib05_snarf_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib05_snarf_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    85620 Apr 11 15:55 lib10_last_login_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1043 Apr 11 15:55 lib10_last_login_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    57044 Apr 11 15:55 lib10_last_login_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   133226 Apr 11 15:55 lib10_mail_filter_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1050 Apr 11 15:55 lib10_mail_filter_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    85171 Apr 11 15:55 lib10_mail_filter_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   965802 Apr 11 15:55 lib10_quota_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1008 Apr 11 15:55 lib10_quota_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   473628 Apr 11 15:55 lib10_quota_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    46968 Apr 11 15:55 lib11_imap_quota_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib11_imap_quota_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   104898 Apr 11 15:55 lib11_trash_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib11_trash_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib11_trash_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   137326 Apr 11 15:55 lib15_notify_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1015 Apr 11 15:55 lib15_notify_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    88574 Apr 11 15:55 lib15_notify_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    27414 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_autocreate_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1043 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_autocreate_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    23038 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_autocreate_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   129194 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_expire_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1015 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_expire_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    85926 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_expire_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1305544 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_fts_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      994 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_fts_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   726452 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_fts_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    31444 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_listescape_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1043 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_listescape_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    23946 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_listescape_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   112888 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_mailbox_alias_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1064 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_mailbox_alias_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    75675 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_mailbox_alias_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   108922 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_mail_log_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1069 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_mail_log_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    73879 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_mail_log_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   895296 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_push_notification_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1132 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_push_notification_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   400667 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_push_notification_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    89268 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_quota_clone_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1050 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_quota_clone_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    59419 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_quota_clone_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    97380 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_replication_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_replication_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_replication_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   966668 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_virtual_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_virtual_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_virtual_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   202898 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_zlib_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_zlib_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib20_zlib_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   395314 Apr 11 15:55 lib21_fts_squat_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1073 Apr 11 15:55 lib21_fts_squat_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   268310 Apr 11 15:55 lib21_fts_squat_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   133856 Apr 11 15:55 lib30_imap_zlib_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib30_imap_zlib_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib30_imap_zlib_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   289408 Apr 11 15:55 lib90_stats_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib90_stats_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib90_stats_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    92344 Apr 11 15:55 lib95_imap_stats_plugin.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib95_imap_stats_plugin.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 lib95_imap_stats_plugin.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6998076 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    91210 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-compression.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1112 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-compression.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       31 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-compression.so -> libdovecot-compression.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       31 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-compression.so.0 -> libdovecot-compression.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    53256 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-compression.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1497266 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-dsync.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1105 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-dsync.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-dsync.so -> libdovecot-dsync.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-dsync.so.0 -> libdovecot-dsync.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   803325 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-dsync.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   348236 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-fts.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1052 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-fts.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       23 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-fts.so -> libdovecot-fts.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       23 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-fts.so.0 -> libdovecot-fts.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   249030 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot-fts.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      993 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   260264 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-lda.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1091 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-lda.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       23 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-lda.so -> libdovecot-lda.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       23 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-lda.so.0 -> libdovecot-lda.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   164433 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-lda.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   665568 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-login.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1081 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-login.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-login.so -> libdovecot-login.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-login.so.0 -> libdovecot-login.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   381322 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-login.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       19 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot.so -> libdovecot.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       19 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot.so.0 -> libdovecot.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3680177 Apr 11 15:54 libdovecot.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   156056 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-sql.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1052 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-sql.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       23 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-sql.so -> libdovecot-sql.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       23 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-sql.so.0 -> libdovecot-sql.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    96051 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-sql.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 16781016 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-storage.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1080 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-storage.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-storage.so -> libdovecot-storage.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-storage.so.0 -> libdovecot-storage.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  7621008 Apr 11 15:55 libdovecot-storage.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    44698 Apr 11 15:55 libfs_compress.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 libfs_compress.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        0 Apr 11 15:55 libfs_compress.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   523552 Apr 11 15:54 libssl_iostream_openssl.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1058 Apr 11 15:54 libssl_iostream_openssl.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   272891 Apr 11 15:54 libssl_iostream_openssl.so
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Apr 11 15:55 stats
```

Comment: Please post the output of "ls -l /usr/lib/dovecot/"

Comment: @tim thanks for the response. I posted the output in the mail post.

Comment: Your lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so has 0 bytes length

Comment: @ALex_hha You are correct. Probably the file is corrupt. Some other files are 0 bytes as well. How do I go about fixing them?

Comment: It would depend on how the dovecot was built. I have tried dovecot-2.2.23.tar.gz without any problem